# Record an entire conversation Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to record a entire conversation from Discord.JS v12. But, I'm don't really good in audio manipulation and other things like that.
I've this code :

```js
const c = message.member.voice?.channel;
        if(!c) {
            // The user is not in voice channel
            return message.channel.send("");
        }
        switch(args?.[0]?.toLowerCase()){
            case 'on':
                if(this.vocals.find(r => r.c === c.id && r.u === message.author.id)){
                    // The user have already an record launched
                    return message.channel.send("Vous avez déjà un enregistrement de démarré.");
                }
                const flux = await c.join();
                const receiver = flux.receiver;
                const audioChunk = this.createNewChunk((message.member.nickname || message.author.username).replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, ''));
                this.vocals.push({
                    c: c.id,
                    u: message.author.id,
                    s: Date.now(),
                    r: audioChunk
                });
                flux.on('speaking', (user, speaking) => {
                    if (speaking) {
                        const audioStream = receiver.createStream(user, { mode: 'pcm' });
                        audioStream.on('data', (chunk) => audioChunk.write(chunk));
                    }
                });
                return message.channel.send("L'enregistrement a bien été lancé avec succès !")
                break;
            case 'off':
                let f = this.vocals.find(r => r.c === c.id);
                const channel = this.bot.channels.cache.get(f.c);
                const members = channel.members.array();
                f = this.vocals.find(r => r.c === c.id &&
                    (members.find(r => r.user.id === message.author.id) &&
                        r.u === message.author.id));
                if(!f){
                    // The user doesnt have any record
                    return message.channel.send("Vous n'avez aucun enregistrement de démarré.");
                }
                console.log(f);
                f.r.close();
                return message.channel.send("L'enregistrement s'est bien terminé avec succès !", )
                break;
            default:
                // const embed = ...
                return message.channel.send(
                    this.help.usage.replace(/{prefix}/g, this.bot.config.prefix)
                )
                break;
        }
```

And the createNewChunk function :

```js
createNewChunk(name) {
    return new wav.FileWriter(`./records/record-${name}.wav`);
}
```

But, when the users stop speaking in the channel, the record is stopped. Do you know how I can avoid this ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so It's really simple to do.

You have to create a audio chunck with Buffer. Then, detect when nobody is speaking. And you can push every 20ms your Buffer into the Stream.

```js
const { Buffer } = require('buffer');
const emptyBuffer = Buffer.alloc(3840, 0); // You create a Buffer with a length of 3840, and a value to 0 (no sound).
```

Then, you have to put all your users into an array :

```js
const users = [];
flux.on('speaking', (user, speaking) => {
                    if (speaking) {
                        users.push(user.id);
                        const audioStream = receiver.createStream(user, { mode: 'pcm' });
                        audioStream.on('end', () => {
                            users.splice(users.findIndex(r => r == user.id), 1); // Remove the users of users speaking array.
                        });
                    }
                });
```

And THEN, you can add your buffer with no sound :

```js
var emptyInterval = setInterval(() => {
                    if(users.length < 1){
                        audioChunk.write(emptyBuffer);
                    }
}, 20)
```

For stop the stream, stop clear the interval of emptyInterval and stop your event flux.on('speaking').

Works for nodejs v16 and more. I dont know if for nodejs v14 or lower it work.